# Recursively loop through a PHP array to manipulate data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a PHP array but I only ever get back my original data. I think it has something to do with when I break the loop

```
$newData = $this->seperateKeyValuePairs($data);

private function seperateKeyValuePairs($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $item)
    {
      if( is_array($item) ) $this->seperateKeyValuePairs($item);

      if( is_string($key) && $this->stringStartsWith($key, 'is_') ) {
        $item = $this->makeBoolean($item);
      }

    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Uh, this doesn't make much sense. Can you a.) show us the array?, and 2.) tell us what you mean by " I only ever get back my original data"

Comment: You are setting `$item` to a value, but that doesn't update the original array.  You probably want `foreach($array as $key => &$item)`, so that way you're using references and the array will get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
$item = $this->makeBoolean($item);
```

You change the value of item. Item is not a pointer to the value in the array, but a copy of it, so the value in the array remains unchanged. What you want to do instead is this:

```
$array[$key] = $this->makeBoolean($item);
```

In the same spirit, you have to change

```
if( is_array($item) ) $this->seperateKeyValuePairs($item);
```

to

```
if( is_array($item) ) $array[$key] = $this->seperateKeyValuePairs($item);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the trick. I completely overlooked passing the reference.